# How to trim a large video with ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am trying to trim a video that is 75 GB size and 1 hour and 28 minutes long

I only want to get 7 seconds out of it

When I try this

```
ffmpeg -i Replay.mp4 -ss 01:21:24.0000 -to 01:21:32.0000 -acodec copy -vcodec copy ShortReplay2.mp4
```

I get this

```
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A
```

It's stuck and nothing happens, have waited for about 30 minutes and is still stuck

However when I try trimming it from the beginning of the video

```
ffmpeg -i Replay.mp4 -ss 00:00:00.000 -to 00:20:00.000 -acodec copy -vcodec copy ShortReplay2.mp4
```

It works without issues

Is it because the file size is too big and the program takes too long to read it? What can I do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Option placement matters

You can try using `-ss` as an input option (before `-i`). This will immediately seek to the closest seek point before the declared `-ss` position. Note that when `-ss` is used as an input option the `-to` option behaves the same as the `-t` option.

If you find this is not accurate enough you may have to use `-ss` as an output option and/or re-encode instead of [stream copy](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy). As an output option it is slower, so it is possible you simply did not wait long enough for it to fully decode to your position.

## Example

```
ffmpeg -ss 01:21:24 -i input.mp4 -t 7 -c copy output.mp4
```

## Also see

- [`ffmpeg` tool documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html)
- [FFmpeg Wiki: Seeking](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking)